# Несовпадение брейкпоинтов с кодом

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Периодически замечаю, что в студии слетают брейпоинты.
Раньше помогал clean - rebuild.
Но сегодня что-то не помогает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например вот, бряк на строку 125 не ставится ни в какую, и соответственно дальше по файлу все бряки начинают плыть.

Может быть известны причины и средства борьбы с такими ситуациями?

Comment: Это дебаг или все же релиз?..

Comment: @Harry это дебаг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем это мои любимые переводы строк.
Если глянуть в hex-редакторе, то после скобочки на строке 123 вместо ожидаемых двух переводов строки 0x0d 0x0a 0x0d 0x0a я вижу только 0x0d 0x0d 0x0a, студия видимо умеет обрабатывать такое дело и корректно отображает в редакторе два перевода строки, а вот отладчик считает эти три символа всего за один перевод строки. После починки переводов строки все стало ок.

Comment: А причиной этому стало копирование кода из другого репозитория, где используются только 0x0d символы для перевода строк)